# How do I parse/request objects from AWS S3 to populate a custom UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, xcode6, uicollectionview

I am looking to achieve an interface similar to that of iBooks, where there is a master view that contains thumbnail images of books/magazines/articles in a grid form, like so:

[image]

Now I am just inferring that they used a custom UICollectionView to achieve this interface, however if there is another method, I am well open to implement it. My question is, I have all my thumbnail images/objects uploaded in a bucket back in Amazon s3, how do i parse those onto a custom UICollectionView to populate it, creating the same interface as shown above? what code should I implement in swift?

Comment: Are the items you plan to show in your collectionview static (finite number of items hardcoded into the app) or dynamic (your app fetches items from a backend server/service)?

Comment: dynamic, my app will fetch them from my backend in amazon s3 @gmat1014

Comment: so what do you suggest? @gmat1014

Comment: Still a little unsure about what your setup is but... You could use NSURLSession to download each thumbnail, store the data in CoreData, then query for it and assign it in your collectionview's cellForItemAtIndexPath method. Check out this example on how to use NSURLSession https://github.com/vandadnp/iOS-8-Swift-Programming-Cookbook/blob/master/chapter-networking/Downloading%20Data%20in%20the%20Background%20Using%20NSURLSession/Downloading%20Data%20in%20the%20Background%20Using%20NSURLSession/ViewController.swift

Comment: my setup is as described above, i want to achieve that exact interface. A grid view of thumbnails. Ok i will check that out @gmat1014

Comment: S3 is object storage. It sounds like you need some server code and a simple database to hold the thumbnail filenames/urls of your S3 objects; along with any other associated data belonging to each item. (that's how I would implement this anyway.) I don't fully understand how you plan to only use S3.

Comment: Unless of course, your items are actually static and you're just using S3 to serve the thumbnail image files. That would be the only way I know of to just use S3

Comment: yes I'm just using s3 to serve/host my thumbnail images. If i should get more in depth, Parse is my mobile backend service, there cloud storage wouldn't be suffice, so i chose s3 as my host. @gmat1014

Comment: does that make sense @gmat1014

Comment: Now I understand. Are you sure Parse won't suffice? I know they have a 10MB file limit, are your files that big???

Comment: here's the thing, the app is basically one similar to iBooks, meaning those thumbnails when selected will load a full PDF file onto the screen for the viewers reading. Now yes parse does have a 10MB limit, so my PDF files exceed that. I figured instead of separating things by putting my thumbnails in parse, and PDF files in s3, why not throw everything in s3. Make sense? @gmat1014

Comment: would you be interested in a chat? @gmat1014

Comment: Yep, makes sense. Although you will not benefit from Parse's image caching functionality if you do that. Caching will greatly improve load time. And it's a bit of work implementing on your own. NSURLSession will enable you to download your thumbnails. My suggestion above still applies.

Comment: can we move this to a chat? i would like to send you visuals of the actual specifics @gmat1014

Comment: Im a little bogged down with another project. Would love to help more. Sorry.

Comment: yes no problem, so quickly. do you think i should separate them so i can utilize the caching of parse and being the PDF's are too large for parse, or should i keep them all together in s3 @gmat1014

Comment: I would separate them

Comment: ok thanks, so i was thinking maybe store the uploaded PDF files from s3's metadata to parse somehow? is that possible? @gmat1014

Comment: All you would need to store in parse is the filename of the pdf (which is tacked on, if I remember correctly, to your bucket url) and then use that filename in your app to generate the url and make the download request with NSURLSession.

Comment: my thing is this, in a table class in parse, how do i go about storing that file name? @gmat1014

Comment: Make a column called filename with type string, no?

Comment: i suppose, can i please interest you in a chat, i won't bug you, i have a great deal of knowledge i just want your opinion on little details @gmat1014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the following:

1. Fetch JSON from the server that describes available items. You can use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for this.
2. Parse the JSON data into objects
3. Create a UICollectionViewController and UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclasses that define iBooks-like UI (you can take a look at [this](https://github.com/m1entus/MZBookshelfCollectionViewLayout) and [this](https://markpospesel.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/decorationviews/) examples)
4. It would be better to use some opensource solution for image loading/caching as well. Like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/m1entus/MZBookshelfCollectionViewLayout)

Comment: okay i will definitely be implementing this method in a few hours

Comment: when you say parse the JSON data into objects meaning create a custom class, and custom objects that have these parsed links to the thumbnails in side them? in the form of a function correct?

Comment: Almost. Here you have two options. The easiest one is to get NSDictionary from NSData object (that you receive from the server) via `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` and use it. The best solution is to define a class that describes iBooks item and create the array of objects from JSON data with  [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON), [Argo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo) or similar.

Comment: so i should still be using alamofir to make the request?

Comment: You can use [NSURLSession](https://medium.com/swift-programming/learn-nsurlsession-using-swift-ebd80205f87c) or [Alamofire](http://nshipster.com/alamofire/) do get the data from the server.

Comment: how do i get the JSON version data of my thumbnails and PDF's in s3?

Comment: I didn't have a chance to work with S3. As far as I got it they don't have JSON API. That is why you should pre-define JSON data at S3 with file names, bucket names, etc. for your thumbnails and PDFs. After that download JSON with `AWSS3TransferManager` and [S3GetObjectRequest](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxJFT163EJ18CA/Downloading-Large-Files-from-Amazon-S3-with-the-AWS-SDK-for-iOS) for large files from [AWS iOS SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios). Or do it yourself with `AFNetworking`/`Alamofire`/...

Comment: when you say pre-define JSON data, meaning at the time of uploading the files, creating the bucket names, i should write them in JSON format or? can you elaborate on that a little bit